# What happens if to introduce infinite and infinitesimel quantities this way?

Tags: nonstandard-analysis, infinitesimals

What if to introduce $\varepsilon$ and $\omega=1/\varepsilon$ from the following equation as a definition?

$$\left(1+\varepsilon\right)^{1/\varepsilon}=e$$

or such $\varepsilon$ that $e^\varepsilon=1+\varepsilon$ and $\varepsilon\ne 0$ as a definition.

Can we deduce other properties of $\varepsilon$ from here?

Comment: Do you want that to be literally equal, or just that the difference of the two sides is infinitesimal?

Comment: @Hurkyl literally equal.

Comment: $(1+x)^{1/x}$ is strictly descending in the vicinity of $x=0$, so there aren't any nonzero infinitesimals of nonstandard analysis that satisfy $(1+\epsilon)^{1/\epsilon} = e$. Formulations of infinitesimals with $\epsilon^2 = 0$ probably wouldn't apply either, since I think they would want $(1+\epsilon)^{1/\epsilon} = e(1 - \epsilon/2)$ if it is to make sense at all.

Comment: @Hurkyl what if to consider $\varepsilon$ not just an infinitesimal but as just some new algebraic element with this property?

Comment: @Hurkyl well I think this question can be closed because in dual numbers https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_number we have exactly that: $\exp(\varepsilon)=1+\varepsilon$

Answer (score 2):

I cannot answer if this leads to any inconsistencies, although it probably does, but I know that Euler handled limits in this way. In his work "Introductio in analysin infinitorum", he wrote proofs like:

Assume $\epsilon$ is infinitesimally small and $\omega$ is infinitely large. Then $\mathfrak{l}(1+\epsilon)=\epsilon$ ($\mathfrak{l}$ was the shorthand for logarithm) and therefore $\mathfrak{l}\left((1+\epsilon)^\omega\right)=\omega\epsilon$. But if we set $x=(1+\epsilon)^\omega$, we obtain $1+\epsilon=x^{\frac{1}{\omega}} \iff \epsilon=x^{\frac{1}{\omega}}-1$. Therefore $\mathfrak{l}(x)=\omega\epsilon=\omega\left(x^{\frac{1}{\omega}}-1\right)$.

With this argumentation, he proved $\ln(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}n\left(x^{\frac 1 n}-1\right)$, and it is truthfully astonishing, how he could proof these things, if we consider that it isn't at all mathematically rigorous by means of todays standards.

So I think, if you have the right intuitions, you can obtain really nontrivial results using such definitions, but a lack of precision is undeniable.

Nevertheless, such assumptions even lead Euler to make some questionable statements, like:
$$
\sum_{p\space prime} \frac{1}{p}=\ln\ln(+\infty)
$$

Comment: Thank you for pointing out Euler's work. It seems this definition leads exactly to the system of dual numbers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_number In dual numbers we have exactly $\exp(\varepsilon)=1+\varepsilon$ although the first form of the definition does not work because division by $\varepsilon$ is undefined.

Comment: That's not a questionable statement. It is unquestionable that he meant that the divergence is asymptotical to $\ln\ln(n)$.

Answer (score 2):

Lets say you define the ring $K$ as $ \mathbb{R} $ with $\varepsilon$ and all the elements generated by $\varepsilon$

Assumptions:
1) $\varepsilon$ is positive
2) The rule that "A finite number of additions or products of positive numbers results in a positive number" that applies to $ \mathbb{R} $ also applies to $K$
3) Series expansions that apply to $ \mathbb{R} $ also applies to $K$

If you look at the series expansion for the exponential function

$$exp(x) = 1 + x^1/1! + x^2/2! + \dots $$

then we would have
$$exp(\varepsilon) = 1 + \varepsilon + y$$
where $y$ is "positive" which would seem to contradict the definition.

I guess my conclusion is that series expansions would not be well behaved when using this new $ \varepsilon$.

Comment: "would seem to contradict the definition" - it would not if $\varepsilon^2=0$ as in dual/parabolic numbers. The given definition as I figured out leads exactly to the dual numbers system.

Comment: Yes, good point. I broadened my second assumption to include more of the spirit I was going for to include multiplication. So $\varepsilon*\varepsilon=0$ would contradict the second assumption. It seems any ring you create, such as the dual numbers would have to break at least one assumption.